# Having problem to add local hasura to Google cloud run

Tags: deployment, cloud, gcloud, hasura

Do you have some information or tutorial to add local hasura to google cloud run.

I already successfully set the hasura at google cloud run, but it seems i have a problem to connect it with our local database in hasura.

i got an error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) Unable to read file [cloudbuild.yaml]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cloudbuild.yaml'
```

Is there something is not configured yet or?

Best

Zaid

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague.

The error you reference is Google Cloud Build and suggests that you're trying `gcloud builds submit ...` and this is failing because the command is unable to find a `cloudbuild.yaml` file. It's entirely probably you want to do the deployment using Cloud Build but you'll need to create the `cloudbuild.yaml` file for this to work.

For those of unfamiliar with "hasura", do you mean [hasura.io](https://hasura.io)?

This appears to require a container image running that defaults to port `:8080` (which is good as that's a default assumed by Cloud Run) and a connection to a PostreSQL database.

If you're using Cloud SQL to run PostgreSQL, you can follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run)

Comment: Indeed, it seems an that the issue is related to not having set a `cloudbuild.yaml` file properly. Just to complement this answer, here are the docs on [creating a Cloud Build config file](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/create-basic-configuration#creating_a_build_config) and [Build configuration overview](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config)

Comment: Thank you for the answer... yes i want to create cloudbuild.yaml but it seems its not working yet.  i will try to follow the instruction and let you know